# Use of undeclared identifier 'cam' / Flutter/iOS/XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

Can someone please help? I'm working on a project and I have never really used XCODE, or built for iOS before...

I need to figure out why this project I'm working on won't build .. Can someone please help me?

I feel like I'm going crazy and I need to get this sorted :(

[image]

Comment: Move the if available to enclose the whole block. Current `cam` goes out of scope at line 844. You need the else of if available to be after, at least, line 864.